# trying to understand node js server concept

Tags: javascript, node.js

I’m good at jQuery but I’m new to modern js frameworks introduced over the last couple of years. I understand how index.html works in the following example and I can infer that server.js serves the request made from index.html. However, I’m not clear on how server.js gets initialized.

http://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/send-e-mail-node-js/#comment-18703

There does not appear to be a src ref from index.html to server.js which appears to indicate that server.js gets initialized in some other way although that's all I'm able to infer. This is a knowledge gap on my end but can you explain how to initialize server.js so that it can be called by index.html?

Comment: you start node server by typing in `node server.js`

Comment: Node.js doesn't have a direct tie to HTML, jQuery, etc. It's a JavaScript runtime that's often "server-side," operating separately from the browser, typically started from a command line -- `$ node server.js`. http://blog.modulus.io/absolute-beginners-guide-to-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a platform built on top of javascript. Non blocking threads due to its asynchronous behaviour, still event driven.

Node.js provision many use cases. You can refer [this](http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js) & [this](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-use-cases).

Coming to your point is required to create a [webserver](http://nodejs.org/) on top of node.js *http/https* modules. Once this server started by nodejs, it is ready to serve http clients.

Open source dev communities built some of great web app framework like [express](http://expressjs.com/) which are easy to learn. [github](http://github.com), [npmjs](http://npmjs.org) are full of great node modules / packages which are ready to plug into your app.